# Squiggly transition in automaton

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, automata, edge

I need to make an automaton, that looks like this:

[image]

I can only do the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata,
            quotes,
            positioning
            }

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, >=stealth', auto, node distance=0.5cm and 1.5cm, semithick, initial text=]
    \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_{0}$};
    \node[state, accepting] (q1) [right = of q0] {$q_{1}$};

    \path[->, shorten >=1pt]
    (q0) edge node {$a^n$} (q1)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

How do I get the squiggly edge?

Comment: What is the meaning of this squiggly transition?

Comment: @projetmbc It will be used to denote n states with transitions under 'a' between them:
(q0, a, q1), (q1, a, q2), ... , (q(n-1), a, qn)

Comment: Decoration [`snake`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.3.2)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that works almost perfectly, but the head of the arrow is not aligned. ([picture](https://imgur.com/a/qlX7fDx))

Comment: @McDuck [One tutorial shows the solution.](https://tikz.dev/tutorial-nodes#sec-3.12) The option [`post length`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-decorations#pgf/decorations/post:length), the manual also uses the `snake` decoration as an example.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Qrrbrbirlbel, here is the solution:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, >=stealth', auto, node distance=0.5cm and 1.5cm, semithick, initial text=]
    \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_{0}$};
    \node[state, accepting] (q1) [right = of q0] {$q_{1}$};

    \path[->, shorten >=1pt]
    (q0) edge [decorate, decoration={snake,amplitude=.6mm,segment length=3mm,post length=2mm}] node {$a^n$} (q1)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You should also add a pre length. That would be prettier.